# Debugging python programs in emacs

Tags: python, debugging, emacs, pdb

How do I debug python programs in emacs? I'm using `python-mode.el`

I've found references suggesting:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
```

but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Type `M-x cd` to change directory to the location of the program you wish to debug.
Type `M-x pdb`. You'll be prompted with `Run pdb (like this): pdb`. Enter the name of the program (e.g. `test.py`).

At the `(Pdb)` prompt, type `help` to learn about how to use pdb.

Alternatively, you can put

```
import pdb 
pdb.set_trace()
```

right inside your program (e.g. `test.py`). Now type `M-x shell` to get a shell prompt. When you run your program, you'll be dumped into `pdb` at the point where `pdb.set_trace()` is executed.

Comment: Using pdbtrack (through M-x shell) is probably a better solution.  It's much easier to control directories and environments that way.

Comment: @matt with M-x pdb you can set break points in source files and a cursor will show the current position of execution as you step through: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/debug-with-emacs.html

Comment: A graphical tutorial may be found here: http://sunnyeves.blogspot.com/2011/04/debugging-python-on-emacs-ide.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167614/python-mode-in-emacs-no-such-file-or-directory-pdb might be helpful if you don't have a pdb executable, see @sanityinc's comment: create a shell script pdb in any of the dir's in your path with text:
#!/bin/bash
exec python -m pdb "$@"

Comment: Why the method one doesn't work for me. emacs complains that it cannot find the provided .py file.

Comment: anyone know how to get the 'red-dot' on breakpoints similar to gdb?

Comment: The key binding to set a breakpoint is C-x C-a C-b in recent emacs versions.

Answer (score 22):

For me, I needed to replace the default "pdb" with

```
python -m pdb myscript.py
```

Answer (score 20):

The [`realgud`](https://github.com/realgud/realgud/) package (available from MELPA) supports PDB (among a gazillion other debuggers), and has a host of neat features that Emac's PDB doesn't have.

The one I like best is the shortkeys mode. Once you start debugging a program, you can press `n`, `s`, `c` etc. right in the source window, instead of having to type these commands in the PDB buffer. It also supports Visual-Studio style keybindings with function keys (`f10`, `f11`, `f5`, etc).

After installing RealGUD, you need to run `M-x load-feature realgud` to load it, and you can start `pdb` with `M-x realgud:pdb`.

Comment: I should add that I have a small conflict of interest. I found the package so neat that I started hacking on it, and now became a co-maintainer.

Comment: realgud looks amazing! I wonder how straightforward it would be to integrate entering realgud/emacs with existing debug-entry flows like setting a trace and running a test with something like `pytest`. Any tips here? Maybe this will do what I'm looking for: https://github.com/realgud/realgud/#tracking-an-existing-debugger-process

Comment: realgud isn't supported in emacs-25, attempting to install it gives "Package `emacs-25` is unavailable" error message, unfortunately till it gets supported by emacs-25 I will need to find an alternative python debugger for emacs-25, or just keep using pdb without the emacs integration

Comment: You have it backwards: it *requires* emacs-25, and you're trying to install it in an older Emacs. (see https://melpa.org/#/realgud for the dependencies)

Comment: looks cool, but it does not seem to be maintained recently.  @Clément do you know what the story is?  Also in emacs-27 `M-x load-feature` does not do anything after a melpa install.

Comment: Lack of time is the main story.  It works OK for me, but I haven't had much time to dedicate to it.  I head that lsp-mode has support for DAP, but I don't know if that supports Python