# Python mode in Emacs: No such file or directory, pdb

Tags: python, debugging, emacs

I have a python script that I want to debug with [python-mode](https://launchpad.net/python-mode). I read in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324758/debugging-python-programs-in-emacs) that I can debug my python script with `M-x pdb`, however I get the following error:

> Searching for program: no such file or directory, pdb

I can provide `python -m pdb my_source_file.py` in the prompt in the minibuffer, but it would be nice if Emacs could infer this command directly from the file on which I run `M-x pdb`

### Update:

#### Running on:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.1 (Tikanga)
- Emacs 23.3.1

#### Differences between paths

I get different paths when I run `M-: exec-path` and when I run `M-: (getenv "PATH")` (the one returned by `M-: (getenv "PATH")`  is longer).

With this:

- Where is `pdb` located? How can I add it to the Emacs path?
- Is there a way to ask Emacs to **also** look into the paths held by the environment variable `PATH`?

Comment: Do you have `pdb` in your path? Have you tried setting the value of the `pdb-path` variable? What result do you get if you evaluate `(py-guess-pdb-path)` in an Emacs Lisp buffer?

Comment: Thanks @LukeGirvin I tried `M-:`  `(py-guess-pdb-path)` and I got `(Debugger entered-Lisp error: (void-function py-guess-pdb-path)`

Comment: Strange, are you running the latest version of python-mode?

Comment: @LukeGirvin Yes, the latest stable version: `6.0.4`

Comment: Try `M-: exec-path RET` and `M-: (getenv "PATH")` to see what `$PATH` Emacs is using. If you're on OSX, it likely won't match what you see in a terminal, so you might want to try [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606954/path-and-exec-path-set-but-emacs-does-not-find-executable/8609349#8609349).

Comment: Thanks @sanityinc. I run both commands, and I can see differences between the paths returned (the environment variable returns a longer list). I have updated my question accordingly

Comment: I presume you've resolved the issue by now. Want to accept my updated answer for this one? :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Further to my comment earlier, and your subsequent update to the question:

First figure out a value for `$PATH` that works in your terminal. Use `which pdb` to find where the `pdb` executable is located.

Then, set the `$PATH` environment variable explicitly in Emacs, and sync it to `exec-path` as follows:

```
(setenv "PATH" "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/some/other/dir")
(setq exec-path (split-string (getenv "PATH") path-separator))
```

It's possible you would need to also explicitly set `PYTHONPATH` or similar environment variables; you can do that using lines like the "setenv" line above, or just use the [exec-path-from-shell elisp package](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell).

*Update*

Okay, so it turns out Emacs' `pdb` command isn't provided by `python-mode`, and it expects to find an executable called "pdb". The easy way to fix this, then is to create a shell wrapper called "pdb", in a directory on your $PATH:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec python -m pdb "$@"
```

(I found a note [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EmacsEditor) suggesting this technique.)

The equivalent under Windows would be a file called pdb.bat, containing:

```
python -u -m pdb %1
```

(The `-u` prevents Python from buffering its output.)

Comment: Thanks @sanityinc. On my shell, `which pdb` returns nothing, `which python` returns `/sw/python-2.7.1/bin/python`. I know I have `pdb` installed because I can debug with `python -m pdb my_file.pdb`. Do you know where I can find `pdb` ?

Comment: Also, when you said that I should set the environment variable $PATH in Emacs explicitly, I am not sure I understand. Does Emacs has its own environment variables? (other than those the shell has?). Is Emacs supposed to inherit the environment variables from the shell?

Comment: Aha, right - so pdb is just a module. See my updated answer above; $PATH is normally the same in Emacs as in your shell, but I had misunderstood your problem, so please ignore that part of my advice.

Comment: I think when you say `string-split` you mean `split-string`.

Comment: @sanityinc, I think another easier way to find which pdb to use is to use the following command: `python -c 'import pdb; print(pdb.__file__)'`

Answer (score 7):

To run the Python Debugger, `M-x pdb` expects to find an executable named `pdb`. While the `pdb` executable may exist in some Python distributions, it doesn't exist in all of them.

A proposal to fix this is in [GNU bug report #21521: pdb default suggested command](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21521).

Until the bug is fixed, you can set the variable `gud-pdb-command-name` to define the command used to launch pdb. In .emacs, add...

```
(setq gud-pdb-command-name "python -m pdb")
```

Answer (score 3):

At a shell prompt type

```
which pdb
```

In Emacs, type `M-x customize`. Select Programming > Tools > Gud. Set the value of `gud-pdb-command-name` to the path returned by `which pdb`.

If your version of Emacs presents a different organization for the customize menu, you could also try

```
C-h v gud-pdb-command-name
```

Then click on the `customize` link, and set the path to `pdb` there.

Though the instructions above are different, I found this out by reading ["Running pdb under emacs"](http://page.sourceforge.net/tricks.html#Running_pdb_under_emacs) .

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom command like this:

```
;; PDB command line
(defun user-python-debug-buffer ()
  "Run python debugger on current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (setq command (format "python -u -m pdb %s " (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)))
  (let ((command-with-args (read-string "Debug command: " command nil nil nil)))
    (pdb command-with-args)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs 23.3.1 and presumably higher, yet another variation is to use the Emacs shell, [Eshell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html) (`M-x eshell`). Under Eshell, there's a pre-existing, Lisp-based definition of pdb. These Lisp functions work in Eshell just like ordinary shell commands.

So `pdb "./manage.py runserver"` will start a Django server, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is going wild saying you gotta make a `pdb` file and make it an executable and then type `./pdb your_code.py`. It is easier than that.

Be where you want to run the debugger from. Probably in your python file, maybe use `M-x cd` to get somewhere.

Then type: `M-x pdb`

It will prompt you with:

`Run pdb (like this):`

You want to make that look like:

`Run pdb (like this): python -m pdb your_code.py`

Sometimes if I want to run my code as a module.

`Run pdb (like this): python -m pdb -m some_package.my_code`

Then type `help` and go read this https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 0):

My answer builds on what @Chad Nouis mentioned.
[a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33811220/2762156)

However, I've added this to python-mode, everytime python-mode loads, it will set `gud-pdb-command-name` to `"python -m pdb"`

```
;; Set the PDB command
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
       (lambda () (setq gud-pdb-command-name "python -m pdb")))
```