# How to change the default pdb command format in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, pdb, python-mode

In python-mode when I edit a python file, if I type in M-x pdb, it will show
Run pdb (like this): pdb filename.py, but it doesn't work, I will have to change it to python -i -m pdb filename.py. I hope the default format to be python -i -m pdb filename.py. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This question could probably be seen as a duplicate of this one:
[Python mode in Emacs: No such file or directory, pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167614/python-mode-in-emacs-no-such-file-or-directory-pdb).

In short you can either:

- create a pdb executable in your path which will call `python -m pdb`
- add the following line to your .emacs/init.el file `(setq gud-pdb-command-name "python -m pdb")`