# Emacs haskell-mode: "Searching for program: no such file or directory, ghci"

Tags: emacs24, haskell-mode

For some reason emacs is not able to find my ghci. I am running Ubuntu 16.04, and followed the instructions in [this tutorial](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md) to the book.

Using `which ghci` I get the path /opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin/ghci. And executing `M-: exec-path` and `M-: (getenv "PATH")` I can see that path correctly printed.

I have tried to explicitly set the PATH variable in emacs like this, which changes nothing since as far as I could tell it was already there. [From this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182668/3103033)

```
(setenv "PATH" "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin/cabal:/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin/ghci")
(setq exec-path (split-string (getenv "PATH") path-separator)
```

The same thing happens when I use 
`(custom-set-variables '(haskell-process-type 'cabal-repl))` namely the error: "Searching for program: no such file or directory, cabal"

I would greatly appreciate help. :) I have no idea what to do, and I haven't found any answers on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was adding the path to the actual executable, rather than the folder in which the executable sits.

So:
`/opt/cabal/1.22/bin/cabal`
should be
`/opt/cabal/1.22/bin/`

and:
`/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin/ghci`
should be
`/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin/`

Comment: Worse happened to me, I had the actual `.../bin` folder but didn't add the trailing slash at the end, should be `.../bin/`